# AWS - SNS notification for backup vault events - cross-account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I'm facing a problem regarding SNS notification.
I would like to prepare a backup policy for Organization where I have w backup policy on the master account and SNS topic also. I'm using Terraform to prepare stack in Cloudformation to create a backup vault for each selected account but when I want to set up the notification then I receive the following error:

```
aws backup put-backup-vault-notifications     \
--backup-vault-name test_backup_vault     \
--sns-topic-arn arn:aws:sns:eu-central-1:XXXXX:cross-account-backup-topic     \
--backup-vault-events RESTORE_JOB_STARTED RESTORE_JOB_COMPLETED RECOVERY_POINT_MODIFIED
 


An error occurred (InvalidParameterValueException) when calling the PutBackupVaultNotifications 
   operation: Provided SNS topic belongs to another account
```

I saw there is an option to grant permission cross-account: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-backup/latest/devguide/sns-notifications.html

How I can achieve this?

Comment: How about using sns add-permisison? https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/sns/add-permission.html

Comment: This is useful for account operation. I think the backup vault does not support the SNS from another account. Can someone confirm this? I did not find a clear answer but when you see this error message I think it is not supported.

Comment: It supports. Refer to [this doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-backup/latest/devguide/sns-notifications.html#specifying-aws-backup-as-a-service-principal) for showing the cross-account access.

Comment: I did exactly as you suggested so I added the policy for SNS on the master account but after this when I was trying to assign SNS for my backup vault then I received the same error:

```An error occurred (InvalidParameterValueException) when calling the PutBackupVaultNotifications operation: Provided SNS topic belongs to another account```

Comment: Sorry, you are correct. I tried but couldn't do myself. Not sure but there are descriptions we need AWS Organizations for multi accounts... so this might be the reason. [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-backup/latest/devguide/manage-cross-account.html)

Comment: I already have an Organization and the backup policy really works as I expected - inheritance and so on but how to resolve a problem with notification? Should I prepare an SNS topic for every account and SNS subscription and approve all subscription requests for every account? Does it make sense?